# Alternative to <> in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I did some searching on this site and couldn't find exactly what I'm looking for, so I hope this isn't a duplicate. I have an issue where a query in a view is taking about 39 seconds to run, which is dragging down a report query that joins to this view multiple times.

To keep this simple I'm going to keep the code simple, but keep the structure exactly as it is on the view. Here is the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT ....
FROM A a
JOIN B b on a.x = b.x
JOIN C c ON c.s = 'P' AND c.y = b.y
JOIN B AS b2 ON b2.y = c.y AND b2.x <> a.x
JOIN B b3 ON b3.x = b2.x
```

The x's and y's are the same column names in all join predicates.

The issue I am having comes with the line AND b2.x <> a.x. Without this, it runs in about 1 second, but with it its always taking over 30 seconds. I've tried rewriting this predicate multiple times:

```
b2.x IN (select b2.x FROM B b2 join A a on b2.x <> a.x) 


b2.x NOT IN (select b2.x FROM b b2 JOIN A a on b2.x <> a.x)

NOT b2.x = a.x
```

OR even removing it and putting in a where clause after the joins, with all of the above varieties and also :

```
WHERE b2.x NOT IN (SELECT x FROM a)

WHERE b2.x (NOT IN SELECT DISTINCT x FROM a)
```

Im running out of ideas and need to figure out a way to optimize this. Any suggestions or hints at what else I can look at? Just running

```
SELECT b2.x from B b2 JOIN A a ON b2.x <> a.x
```

runs very quickly, so I don't think the underlying tables are the issues.

Comment: Add that `b2.x <> a.x` on the WHERE clause

Comment: Can you add the execution plans for both queries? Do they show it hitting different indexes with and without the second clause, or a joining in a different order? Just moving it to the where clause might not help and Oracle can still use it as a join rather than a filter.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the Oracle query parser/execution engine. Try to maybe move the b2.x <> a.x predicate to a WHERE clause.

Comment: I did try this as well, I missed it in my previous post. That did help either.

Comment: As @AlexPoole said, first step when trying to optimize a query is ALWAYS the execution plan. Look for nodes where the number of I/Os or the expected record count is high. If your query is doing a table scan, that usually indicates a need for an index on the scanned table.

Comment: Also, when you say that something "runs very quickly", are you talking about the time required to fetch the first row?  Or to fetch the last row?  If `a` and `b` are reasonably large, `a join b on a.x <> b.x` should be almost a Cartesian join-- every row in `a` would join to almost every row in `b`.  That would produce a huge number of rows so I'd expect it to take a long time (depending on data volumes) to fetch the last row though it would be very quick to return the first few rows.

Answer (score 1):

If the query runs really fast without the condition, but poorly with it, then I might suggest a materialized CTE:

```
WITH abc as (
      SELECT /*+ materialize */...., b2.x as b2x, a.x as ax
      FROM A a JOIN
           B b
           ON a.x = b.x JOIN
           C c
           ON c.s = 'P' AND c.y = b.y JOIN
           B b2
           ON b2.y = c.y AND b2.x <> a.x JOIN
           B b3
           ON b3.x = b2.x
     )
SELECT abc.*
FROM ABC
WHERE b2x <> ax;
```

Comment: What is the idea behind this materialized CTE? The asker says that without the <> condition (AND b2.x <> a.x) the query is sufficiently fast (1 sec.) and that the problem appears only when the condition is present. To me your version of the query is no better than the initial one, since the <> condition is well present in the CTE. Shouldn't we remove the <> in the CTE (so it returns in no more than 1 sec), and then rely on the WHERE clause of the main SELECT to filter out the rows not matching the <> condition ?